# ServiceStack System.IndexOutOfRangeException at JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey

Tags: json, rest, servicestack, indexoutofboundsexception

In my logs, I found a weird error regarding my ServiceStack service. I don't have further information than the following stacktrace and I didn't manage to reproduce the error yet. That's the stacktrace:

```
JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey (ServiceStack.Text.StringSegment value, System.Int32& i)
DeserializeDictionary`1[TSerializer].ParseStringDictionary (ServiceStack.Text.StringSegment value)
(wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_object_StringSegment (ServiceStack.Text.StringSegment)
JsvReader`1[T].ParseStringSegment (ServiceStack.Text.StringSegment value)
JsvReader`1[T].Parse (System.String value)
TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T] (System.String value)
StringExtensions.FromJsv[T] (System.String jsv)
WebServiceException.ParseResponseDto ()
WebServiceException.get_ErrorMessage ()
WebServiceException.get_Message ()
```

I'm not sure where I should start, the service actually only has json enabled and not jsv, and the part where I handle the request is inside a try-catch block, so I'm not sure why the error is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Exception is due to not being able to parse a structured Error `ResponseStatus` thrown in a `WebServiceException` possibly due to returning an unknown Error Response. I've made it so this parsing heuristic doesn't throw an Exception when it fails in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9b8e60c34ba69369721a4e2c443822d0cb93f326).

This change is available from v5.0.3 that's now available on MyGet.

Comment: Thanks! You're awesome! Do you have any idea what the cause of this could be? It seems to appear very randomly.

Comment: @Marcel Not without seeing the Response Body that's causes it.